# Error when using google.protobuf.Struct for dynamic json in my proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am using the below message in my proto file as an example,

```
message Report {
    string name = 1;
    string desc = 2;
    google.protobuf.Struct criteria = 3;
}
```

and generated the go client, server code. When passing the json below

```
{
"name": "My Report",
"desc": "My first report",
"criteria": {"fields": {"sum": "100"}}
}
```

as post request body to an endpoint and unmarshalling using

```
import  "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb"

var u api.Report
if err := jsonpb.Unmarshal(r.Body, &u); err != nil {...
```

I keep getting this error:

```
level=info msg="panic: reflect.Set: value of type map[string]*structpb.Value is not assignable to type map[string]*structpb.Value"
```

I have also tried using gogo/protobuf/jsonpb but no success there too, although I am still importing in my proto file.

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
```

Not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Based on the error it sounds like you might have two copies of the `structpb` package in your project.

Comment: Not sure if thats the issue although I do have both gogo and golang packages. It depends which jsonpb you use and it should pick the correct structpb

Comment: DId you get a solution to this?